# unknown extensions blocked by IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I ran into a rather.. interesting problem.

.por is not a common extension, though it is used by hero lab's for their portfolio of characters. Putting it on my win 7 laptop with IIS 7.5, the filename will be there when a directory listing is generated by the server via directory browsing and using a web browser at the local host.

BUT, attempting to download it results in a 404. The file extension itself points to a real old corel draw file format. This behavior I can replicate easily with a .junk extension as well.

/why/ is this happening? I would like to know not only how it's configured to behave that way but what modules are involved as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension is not mapped to a known mime type - you need to [add a mime type for this extension](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap).

> IIS 7 will not return file types that are not added to the  element or that have mappings in the  element by default. This behavior prevents unauthorized access to files that do not have mappings in the IIS 7 configuration settings.

Comment: Just when I found the answer myself to that exact effect, but the link I did not have. Thank you.

Comment: How does one disable this horrible "feature"?  It completely messes up WebDAV.